# android:animateLayoutChanges="true" availible for api 8?

Tags: android

Is there a way to use layout flag

> android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

in android API 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible. You can look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#animateLayoutChanges) which clearly indicates that this attribute was only made available starting in API 11. If you want to implement layout animations using this old of an API level, you're probably going to have to make them yourself.